# Удаление дубликатов из БД

Tags: mysql, sql

В БД попали дублирующиеся записи. Нужно очистить первую копию (ключевое поле меньше, чем у последующей копии). Пример:

```
uidl    id      date                    spam
533     590     2011-08-09 00:00:02     0
535     AAA     2011-08-09 00:11:12     0
536     590     2011-08-09 00:00:02     1
540     AAA     2011-08-09 00:11:12     1
```

Критерий дубликатов - одинаковые `id` и `date`.

Сейчас использую такой запрос:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM `testing` WHERE 1 GROUP BY date,id
```

Он создает таблицу уникальных (последних) записей.
Но это не совсем удобно, хотелось бы просто удалить каждую первую запись из пары.

Comment: В зависимости от СУБД есть несколько способов удаления дубликатов:
[Как удалить дубликаты строк из таблицы?](http://sql-ex.ru/help/select17.php)

Comment: судя по backticks - топикастер искал решение под mysql

Answer (score 3):

uidl id date spam

```sql
delete from `testing`
 USING `testing`, `testing` as `tmp`
 WHERE (`testing`.`uidl` <`tmp`.`uidl` )
 AND (`testing`.`date`=`tmp`.`date`)  
 AND (`testing`.`id` = `tmp`.`id` )
```

ПРАВКА: добавилась проверка на уникальное поле. Так, для надежности.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from 'table_name' where 'id' in (
SELECT DATA , count( * ) FROM 'table_name' GROUP BY 'uidl' HAVING count( * ) >1
LIMIT 0 , 30);
```

Comment: +1. LIMIT надо только вычистить, который майадмин оставляет...

Comment: >LIMIT надо только вычистить, который майадмин оставляет...
Это размер поля что ли? Честно говоря не понял для чего count( * ) >1
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: count(*)>1 Сообщает, что найденных группировкой полей более одной штуки.
LIMIT начало, количество - говорит, что надо из всех выбранных удалять все, начиная с "начало" и пока не наберется "количество".  
Размер поля тут не при чем...

Comment: в таком виде не сработает - группировка по uidl вообще не имеет смысла, поскольку поле уникальное. date тут не выберется, поскольку его нет в group by

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from testing
where uidl in (
select t.uidl from testing t
join (
select id, date, max(uidl) as md
from testing
group by id, date) m on m.id = t.id and m.date = t.date and m.md > t.uidl)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Doubles AS (
select uidl, id, date, spam
, row_number() over(partition by id, date order by uidl desc) num
from Testing
)

Delete Doubles
Where num > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем в тему, но думаю тоже будет полезно.
Удаляет все дубли и оставляет уникальную запись с самой ранней датой.

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE 

varid numeric;
vardate timestamp;

BEGIN
    FOR varid,vardate IN select id,min(date) from tmp group by id having count(*)>1

    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '% % ',varid,vardate;
        DELETE FROM tmp WHERE id=varid AND date<>vardate; 
    END LOOP;
END
$$;
```