# Как удалить дублирующие товары, но 1 оставить?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
delete product 
group by name
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select17.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление дубликатов из БД](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/25903/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94)

Comment: @Bald там по ссылке не sql server, судя по FROM `testing`

Comment: @PashaPash разве? пробежался по ответам вроде похоже. да и на мой взгляд можно взять алгоритм и применить

Comment: @Bald в SQL Server есть родные методы для поиска первой строки. и возможность удаления по результатам селекта без IN.

Comment: @Bald хотя принят ответ-ссылка на английскую статью. С решением для SQL Server. И на нем уже висит тревога.

Comment: @PashaPash принят ответ ссылка, но не на английскую статью

Comment: @Bald внезапно, там есть переключатель языков и у меня почему-то по умолчанию выбрался английский :(

Comment: @PashaPash и кстати первый коммент ведет туда же. Но все оттуда переписывать ... в целом весь ответ сводится к тому как определить *дубликат*

Comment: @Bald ответ на этот вопрос не сводится к "как определить дубликат". Хотя бы потому, что в SQL Server есть CTE, и красивое решение будет выглядеть не так, как в mysql.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) rnk
    FROM product 
     )
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE rnk > 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Первое самое простое что приходит в голову, это записать данные во временную таблицу дистинком, потом удалить и снова вставить. Совсем не оптимально, но если табличка небольшая будет работать быстро.

```
select distinct name INTO #temp from product

delete product 
group by name
having count(*) > 1

insert into product
select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```